# Proper way to communicate between divs in jquery?

Tags: jquery, dom

This is probably a simple question, and i'm just being dense. I've looked through a few jquery books and nothing has jumped out at me, i'm probably missing something.

I'm looking for the 'proper', best practices way to communicate between divs/dom items on a page?

For example, I have a page with 5 panels that display when a link is chosen, they hide/show/run some code that changes other pieces on the page. Something like this snippet:

```
<ul>
<li><div id="unique_name_1_anchor">Unique div 1</div></li>
<li><div id="unique_name_2_anchor">Unique div 2</div></li>
<li><div id="unique_name_3_anchor">Unique div 3</div></li>
<li><div id="unique_name_4_anchor">Unique div 4</div></li>
</ul>
```

...Somewhere else on the page

```
<div id="unique_name_1_panel">Some panel 1 stuff here</div>
<div id="unique_name_2_panel">Some panel2 stuff here<div>
<div id="unique_name_3_panel">Some panel3 here</div>
<div id="unique_name_4_panel">Some panel4 here</div>
```

The concept being when as user clicks on a unique_name_X_anchor div, some action is performed on the corresponding panel (ie show/hide etc...). What I have been doing now is parsing the id ie ($(this).replace("_anchor","_panel") to get the div id of the other dom element. This just seems clunky and there must be a better/more proper way of doing this. Suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Could you switch from using _anchor just unique_name_1 and select your panel with id + "_panel" ?

Comment: Thanks for the response Adam. Definitely, I could do that, I was viewing that as a very similar solution to the first one -- ie manually constructing the div name based on some naming convention. I wanted to confirm this is commonly used, seems like it could get ugly if you start to have a lot of components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few ideas:

- using the jQuery metadata plugin to add some metadata that points to the corresponding DIV. http://plugins.jquery.com/project/metadata
- Get creative, use another valid DOM element or valid attribute (rel, href) to hold this info
- If you have this data programmatically, set `$('.anchor').data('correspondingPanel')` to the corresponding ID (or some other useful data).
- If indexes will always be the same use the jQuery index method to get the index of the anchor, and show the panel with the same index. http://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: I do like the metadata plugin, will explore this a bit more, thank you for the tip.

Comment: Thanks again for all the suggestions everyone, I think .data() or the metadata plugin will be used, great stuff, thansk for the pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Need you use `id`'s? Would this approach be appropriate?

#### HTML

```
<ul id="anchors">
    <li><div>Unique div 1</div></li>
    <li><div>Unique div 2</div></li>
    <li><div>Unique div 3</div></li>
    <li><div>Unique div 4</div></li>
</ul>

<div id="panels">
    <div>Some panel 1 stuff here</div>
    <div>Some panel2 stuff here<div>
    <div>Some panel3 here</div>
    <div>Some panel4 here</div>
</div>
```

#### jQuery

```
$('#anchors div').click(function() {
    var panel = $('#panels div').eq($(this).index());
    panel.show();
})
```

Comment: Woot! 1337 reputation score FTW!

Comment: The index approach looks like the winner when you are guaranteed the same order in the related components. 

Unfortunately I don't think this will work in my case, the components may be sortable by the user and pulling in data through ajax, so I think the index may change.

Answer (score 0):

something along the line of

give li div a class called divLinks
give panel div class called pabel

```
$('div.divLinks').click(function(){
    $('.panel').hide();
    $('.panel').eq($(this).index()).show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions guys, great stuff. It seems like a common theme I am seeing is to base this interactions on the index, provided they will always be the same set.

Comment: missing single quote - `$('div.divLinks')`

Answer (score 0):

One way is creatively use class names for this.

Given:

```
<div id="unique_name_1_anchor">Unique div 1</div>
<div class="unique_name_1_anchor">Div 1 panel</div>
```

You could do something like:

```
$('#unique_name_1_anchor).click(function(){$('.'+this.id).show()})
```